# Is it possible to autogenerate pipelines from Jenkinsfiles from SCM like in TeamCity KotlinDSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to add SCM git repo once with multiple Jenkinsfiles and I want Jenkins to automatically create Pipelines using these Jenkinsfiles. Something similar to TeamCity where you once create a Kotlin DSL with whole project structure and TC automatically creates nested projects, builds etc. Is it possible in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, you can achieve this by using jobs-dsl plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin